# How can I prove this derangement question

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I need to prove this equation while using combinations but I have no idea how to proceed. I just need a hint. Thank you

$n!=D_n{n\choose 0} + D_{n-1} {n\choose 1} + D_{n-2}{n\choose 2} +... D_0{n\choose n}  $

$D_0=1$

$D_n$ is the number of derangements of an $n$-element set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $n!$ counts the number of permutations of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$. So let $S_{n}$ be the set of permutations.

We can partition $S_{n}$ into $n+1$ sets $X_{0},X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}$ where a permutation $f$ is in $X_{k}$ if and only if it has exactly $k$ fixed points.

So $n!=|S_{n}|=|X_{0}|+|X_{1}|+\ldots +|X_{n}|$.

Now notice that $|X_{k}|={n\choose k}D_{n-k}$ (first choose $k$ fixed points and then choose a derangement of the remaining $n-k$ points.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally got it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $X_n$ instead of $X_k$ in the formula for $n!$? I tried to edit it, but since the edit is just a letter, stackoverflow didn't let me

Comment: @JoseRamirez yes, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

We use double counting as follows:

$n!$ denotes the number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct things. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
n!&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\text{# of arranging $n$ objects with exactly $i$ objects at their respective position}\\ &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\text{# of arranging $n$ objects with exactly $i$ objects not at their respective position}\\ &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}D_i {n\choose i}\\ &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}D_i{n\choose n-i}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks for helping really :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can partition the set of permutations on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

This for $k=0,1,2,\dots,n$ in permutations that leave exactly $k$ elements untouched.

This induces a summation for the number of permutations.